# Squeryl Many to Many: compositeKey(field1, field2) doesn't exist

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0, squeryl

I'm learning Scala (2.11) and the Play Framework, and i'm trying to implement a Many to Many relation between Person and Skill with Squeryl (0.9.5-7). Multiple Persons can share Skills, and a Person can have many Skills.

The Squeryl [docs](http://squeryl.org/relations.html) tell me to do this:

```
class PersonToSkill(val personId: Long, val skillId: Long) extends KeyedEntity[CompositeKey2[Long,Long]] {
  def id = compositeKey(personId, skillId)
}
```

But the compiler tells me this:

```
not found: value compositeKey
[error]   def id = compositeKey(personId, skillId)
[error]            ^
[error] one error found
[error] (compile:compile) Compilation failed
```

Also, i cannot find compositeKey(fieldId, fieldId) in the docs. I have no idea where it it originates from.. 
I'm hoping someone can help me solve my problem, or at least explain me where to look for a solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find `compositeKey` located within [`org.squery.dsl.QueryDsl`](http://squeryl.org/api/index.html#org.squeryl.dsl.QueryDsl)

You'll want to make sure you import `org.squeryl.PrimitiveTypeMode._` which extends QueryDsl. That should resolve the error you are receiving.